# Auto populating <input type=date> with php variables

Tags: php, html, mysql

How do I auto-populate the `<input type=date>` below with PHP variable, `$person->dob`, which is stored in my database table?

I tried the following but it doesn't fill anything in it, just stays `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Here's the code:

```
<l1>Date of Birth <input value="<?= $person->dob; ?>" type="date" name="dob" required></l1>
```

Comment: Which format does the field `dob` have in the database? What do you get when you echo `<?= $person->dob; ?>` not as the input value, but directly in the HTML code.

Comment: @masterfloda It has the format of `dd/mm/yyyy`. Also when I echo it prints it out.

Comment: if my answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it and therefore mark this question as answered.

Comment: It did, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value attribute only accepts values in the format `yyy-mm-dd` (in PHP that's `Y-m-d`). According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Value):

> One thing to note is that the displayed date format differs from the
>   actual value — the displayed date format will be chosen based on the
>   set locale of the user's browser, whereas the date value is always
>   formatted yyyy-mm-dd.

This means you have to convert your date to this format. Ideally, the field in the database is a `date` field, then you should be able to set the output format through whichever ORM layer you are using.

If not, you can convert it with PHPs date functions:

```
<?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($person->dob)); ?>
```

Or with a simple regex, which might be slightly faster:

```
<?= preg_replace('/^(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})$/', '$3-$2-$1', $person->dob); ?>
```